# RxJs distinctUntilChanged() allows emission of same object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable pipeline which when subscribered to calls an API. I am using `distinctUntilChanged` operator to emit next notification only when the current HTTP response is different from previous HTTP response. Even though the API response is the same, `distinctUntilChanged` operator emits the next notification.
I am using `isEqual` function from `lodash` to compare the objects and I see it returns true.

Here's the snippet:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomerFacadeService {
  private eventBus$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
  private cachedCartData$ = this.http.get(
    'https://62c41dc97d83a75e39f0d512.mockapi.io/api/v1/cart'
  );

  cart$ = this.eventBus$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.cachedCartData$),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, current) => {
      const result = isEqual(prev, current);
      console.log('result', result);
      return result;
    }),
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  cacheBust() {
    this.eventBus$.next();
  }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Repo:
https://github.com/phalgunv/caching-data-example

`cart$` observable subscribed in 2 different components via `async` pipe. When I click on "Update" button, a next notification is emitted which causes the HTTP GET API to be called. I expect `distinctUntilChanged` to not emit next notification as the data has not changed. Even thought the object reference may have changed, but since I am using `isEqual` function.

Answer (score 1):

> cart$ observable subscribed in 2 different components via async pipe

This causes 2 separate subscriptions of a cold observable. This means you will get 2 producers for your 2 subscribers. So each subscription is getting a separate `distinctUntilChanged()`. If you want to share a single producer across multiple consumers, this is where you can use `share()` to turn a cold observable into a hot one.

Keep in mind this is essentially putting a `Subject` as a middle-man between your single producer and multiple subscribers. [There are some details](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/ShareConfig) regarding when the `Subject` actually subscribes to the producer, and how it manages its lifecycle. Here, both your components are subscribing upon construction and shouldn't miss any events passed through `share()`. You can look into `shareReplay()` if you need caching for late subscribers.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomerFacadeService {
  private eventBus$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
  private cachedCartData$ = this.http.get(
    'https://62c41dc97d83a75e39f0d512.mockapi.io/api/v1/cart'
  );

  cart$ = this.eventBus$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.cachedCartData$),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, current) => {
      const result = isEqual(prev, current);
      console.log('result', result);
      return result;
    }),
    share(),
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  cacheBust() {
    this.eventBus$.next();
  }
```